# Identifying X close event of a popup window using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, jquery, window

I need to differentiate between user driven close of a popup window using X close button and close through code.

```
var win= window.showModelessDialog("http://localhost/test/test.aspx",'google,....);
//Some manipulations            
//Manipulation ends
if(win!=null && win.open)
{
 win.close();
}
```

Now I have full access over test.aspx and test.aspx.cs.I have a onbeforeunload method defined in test.aspx page which will be called either way I close the window(X close or my code gets executed)I basically want to differentiate my X close and programmatic close so that I can do some backend manipulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
var MyPopup = {

  _win : null,

  _userClosingWindow : true,

  open : function() {
    var _this = this;
    this._win = window.open(...);
    this._win.onbeforeunload = function() {
      if( _this._userClosingWindow ) {
         // closed by user
      }
      else {
        // closed in code
      }
    };
  },

  close : function() {
    this._userClosingWindow = false;
    this._win.close();
  }

};
```

Then you can use MyPopup.open() and MyPopup.close() and still know when the close function is called or when the popup is closed by the user.

Comment: will try this and update you.Will mark it as correct answer if it works

Comment: The concept works, but I'm not sure if the code is 100% correct.

Comment: this._win.onbeforeunload = function () { is not triggered :(

Comment: Well, then there's something wrong in your code. Take a look at http://jsbin.com/umafeq/2/edit . As you can see there the concept works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Model Popup** & include "OK" & "Cancel" Button.

Now you can handle both the "OK" & "Cancel" Button Events.

you can use:

**[AjaxControlToolkit - ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)**

**[jQuery UI - Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)**

Answer (score 1):

```js
// parent
function closePopup(win) {
    win.close();
    // do the magic stuff...
}


// popup (test.aspx)
function closeMe() {
    self.opener.closePopup(window);
}
```

**Update**
As of your comment, just check the `closed` property of the popup. If it is `false`, the popup is still open, otherwise it has already been closed

```
if (win.closed === false) {
    win.close();
    // do magic stuff here
}
```

Comment: closeMe is called onBeforeunload?

Comment: When the popup is closed programmatically call `closeMe()` instead of `window.close()` in `test.aspx`.

Comment: I programatically close window from parent :(